# Discord.py Syntax Error (Discord Bot Javascript)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i get this error after in run the command clear:

if(message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

I dont find my Syntax Error can you help me please?

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'clear',
  description: "Clear messages!",

  if(message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
    async execute(message, args) {
      if(!args[0]) return message.reply("Please enter the amount of messages that you want to clear!");
      if(isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply("Please enter a real number!");

      if(args[0] > 100) return message.reply("You canno't delete more than 100 messages!");
      if(args[0] < 1) return message.reply("You must delete at least one message!");

      await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: args[0]}).then(messages => {
        message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
   } else {
      message.channel.send('I see you dont have the correct permissions');
    }
  });
  }
}
```

Comment: This code isn't within a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put your `if` statement outside of the executable code area. You simply needed to reshift over your code.

New (Reorganized) Code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'clear',
    description: "Clear messages!",

    async execute(message, args) {
        if (message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
            if (!args[0]) return message.reply("Please enter the amount of messages that you want to clear!");
            if (isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply("Please enter a real number!");
            if (args[0] > 100) return message.reply("You cannot delete more than 100 messages!");
            if (args[0] < 1) return message.reply("You must delete at least one message!");

            await message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: args[0] }).then(messages => {
                message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
            })
        } else {
            message.channel.send("You do not have permissions!");
        }
    }
}
```